# stretch image in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I want to implement stretch image function, user can drag each corner to stretch and pinch the image to make it smaller or bigger. Anyone can help? I use C# and xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to write the following on yourself:

1. Add the Image in XAML
2. Add four squares
3. position the squares to the edge
4. add a mousedown handler to the squares and save the square on mousedown to a property
5. add a mousemove handler to your application, check if the property is filled
6. resize the image by calculating the image size. For example for the right-bottom corner (pseudo code):

   image.width=square.offset.x-image.offset.x

   image.height=square.offset.y-image.offset.y
7. Add a mouseup handler to your application and release the square-property.

This is very basic. There are lot of good examples out there, mostly for WPF, but you can reuse it for Windows 8. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20245/WPF-Interactive-Image-Cropping-Control) is a good one, but for image cropping.